# Ola backups happening on both Primary and Secondary AG

Tags: backup, availability-groups, maintenance, ola-hallengren

I configured Ola's scripts on a staging AG configuration to test out the logic. When I checked the backup folder today after a week, I see that the backups are happening both on the primary replica and copy_only backups on the secondary replica.

It is my understanding that the backups are supposed to happen on the secondary replica - And I have configured the AG to "Prefer secondary". I don't want the backups happening on both primary and secondary on this 2 node AG. What can be done for this to work? Please advise.

Answer (score 4):

Validate that:

- Backup Priority is higher on the Secondary instances
- None of the secondaries are excluded
- You are looking at Synchronized (in the AG) databases
- You do not have `OverrideBackupPreference` set in the Ola cmd line

Check your DBName. If I call `sys.fn_hadr_backup_is_preferred_replica` with a `@DatabaseName` that does not exist on the instance it returns a 1. If you have validated all this and it still returns a 1 on both replicas then the issue is not the OLA scripts, the issue is your AG configuration.

---

*<sub>[Community Wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) created from comments by [IanG](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/71181/iang)</sub>*

Answer (score 3):

Use the below to see if the current node is the correct node and only run the backup if so:

```
SELECT sys.fn_hadr_backup_is_preferred_replica (@DatabaseName)
```

Comment: I created  a backup schedule with the maintenance plans and they are happening only on the secondary replica as expected.  I am guessing something else needs to be changed in the ola script for it to properly work